# Unity3D - Displaying a message at the border of the screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to display a kind of banner everytime the player enters a new location. This should be at the very left border of the screen. My problem is that my current solution behaves inconsistently across resolutions. On higher resolutions the banner is positioned further to the right than needed.

[image]

I also use a piece of code to properly position the text every time it is displayed.

```
public class AreaName : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static AreaName instance;

    void Start ()
    {
        if (instance)
            Destroy(this);
        else
            instance = this;

        BannerBase = transform.FindChild("BannerBase").GetComponent<Image>();
        NameDisplay = BannerBase.transform.FindChild("BannerText").GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    private Image BannerBase;
    private Text NameDisplay;

    public static void Display (string areatitle)
    {
        int width = TextWidth(instance.NameDisplay, areatitle);
        instance.BannerBase.rectTransform.position = new Vector3(-305 + width, instance.BannerBase.transform.position.y, 0);
        instance.NameDisplay.text = areatitle;
        print(width);
    }

    private static int TextWidth (Text obj, string text)
    {
        int totalLength = 0;

        Font myFont = obj.font;  //chatText is my Text component
        CharacterInfo characterInfo = new CharacterInfo();

        char[] arr = text.ToCharArray();

        foreach (char c in arr)
        {
            myFont.GetCharacterInfo(c, out characterInfo, obj.fontSize);

            totalLength += characterInfo.advance;
        }

        return totalLength;
    }
}
```

Are there any simple errors that I am overseeing? Or am I just understanding the Unity UI system wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to code nothing to do that.

You have put your banner at the lower left corner of the screen, with a (0,0) pivot, that's all right, but, why is it positioned at x: -320?

If you put your banner at -320 for some reason, at native resolution it probably will work as expected, but if you have activated the Canvas Resizer, at other resolutions it will be moved since is not positioned at the corner at all.

Comment: The problem is that the banner has an end. I thought that i would have to reposition it according to the size of the text.

Comment: Yes, but what's the sense of putting some of the banner out of the screen?

You can add a Content Size Fitter to your Text, then put a image background as a child then it will fit the Text size.

Please, attach an image of what you have and what are you trying to achieve so I can help you easily.